# Iterate only through the rows corresponding to a specific hour of a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How do you iterate through a pandas DataFrame based on the hour? Let's say we want to iterate only through the rows corresponding to the 10:00 hours; I've been using the "between_time()" method but is not enough flexible when using it with list comprehensions. What is the best approach for this?

```
                      Value
Time                                                                           
2018-11-09 10:00:00  3386.0
2018-11-09 11:00:00  2477.0
2018-11-09 12:00:00  2110.0
2018-11-09 13:00:00  4337.0
2018-11-12 10:00:00  3023.0
2018-11-12 11:00:00  2307.0
2018-11-12 12:00:00  1824.0
```

Comment: You can filter your data frame. `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` then `df.loc[df.index.hour == 10]`

Comment: Iterate and do what? As @rafaelc said, you can filter your dataframe and do the iteration on that `df`.

Comment: @rafaelc read your comment after my answer - if you post an answer i'll remove mine.

Answer (score 1):

Start by converting your index to a date format:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

You can iterate through the rows where the hour within datetime is equal to a given value in a lot of ways but this seems like the easiest:

```
for row in df.loc[df.index.hour == 10].iterrows():
    #insert task here
    print(row)
    print(row[0])
```

With this set up you could edit the value or add something to the row etc.

Comment: Yes, when using it only the *df.loc[df.index.hour == 10]* it works perfect, but when using it in the for loop suggested, it prints all the hours ignoring the filter. Am I missing something? (novice coder here), also, is there a way to use it with *list comprehensions* as I've read that those are more efficient. What I'm trying to achieve is to compare the values between different rows/hours, for example: if 10:00 Value is greater than 11:00 Value, and return the answer in a new column next to the Value column

Comment: thanks for the comment - my original answer printed the data frame when the row should have been referenced. answer has been updated. the last section of your comment is a separate question that is pretty easy with pandas. you'd need to provide an example of the output though.

Comment: if you do ask that question, leave a comment and I should be able to help with that

Comment: Doing it like this:

*for row in df.loc[df.index.hour == 10]:
    #insert task here
    print(row.Value)*

it gives an error pointing: *"string indices must be integers"*

Comment: I've added the other related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59219870/compare-values-based-on-inner-day-time-hours-and-return-the-answer-to-a-new-c  Thank you! :)

Comment: No luck. it only prints the name of the column(s) :( . Also would be good to reference the desired column by its name (because of many columns, it's difficult to reference them by index)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203786/discussion-between-brddawg-and-fx757).

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through

```
df.assign(stamp=lambda x: x.index.hour * 3600 + x.index.minute * 60 + x.index.second).query('stamp == 36000')
```