# Compare values based on inner day time (hours), and return the answer to a new column in the same pandas DataFame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to compare values in between different rows based on a hour datetime index.

For example: if 10:00 Value is greater than 11:00 Value on the same day, then return the Boolean value to a new column.

Initial data:

```
                    Value
Time                                                                           
2018-11-09 10:00:00    25
2018-11-09 11:00:00    45
2018-11-09 12:00:00    15
2018-11-09 13:00:00    95
2018-11-12 10:00:00    85
2018-11-12 11:00:00    35
2018-11-12 12:00:00    55 
2018-11-12 13:00:00    65

dataframe snippet:
import pandas as pd
data = [25,45,15,95,85,35,55,65]
index = ['2018-11-09 10:00:00','2018-11-09 11:00:00','2018-11-09 12:00:00','2018-11-09 13:00:00'
         ,'2018-11-12 10:00:00','2018-11-12 11:00:00','2018-11-12 12:00:00','2018-11-12 13:00:00']

df = pd.DataFrame(data,index,columns=['Value'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Desired Output:

```
                    Value   10h-Val 11h-Val 12h-Val 13h-Val 12h-Val>11h-Val? 
Time                                                                           
2018-11-09 10:00:00    25       25         
2018-11-09 11:00:00    45               45
2018-11-09 12:00:00    15                       15                   False
2018-11-09 13:00:00    95                               95
2018-11-12 10:00:00    85         85            
2018-11-12 11:00:00    35               35 
2018-11-12 12:00:00    55                       55                    True
2018-11-09 13:00:00    65                               65
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your desired output. Do you want only `12h-Val > 11-hVal`? or do you want all pairwise comparisons?

Comment: The comparison can be arbitrary, for this case, only the *12h-Val > 11-hVal*

Answer (score 1):

the quickest method for adding those columns would be structured like this:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['10h-val'] = df.loc[df.index.hour == 10].Value
df['12h-Val>11h-Val?'] = ''
```

you'll notice pandas will create a new name with the header in the square brackets on the left and set the value equal to the column Value where the hour equals 
10 and we'll need to populate the comparison column.

for the comparison column, we'll loop through the rows of our dataframe and update those matching a the base hour:

```
base_hr = 12
comp_hr = 11

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index.hour == base_hr:
        row = row.copy()
        base_value = row.Value
        comp_value = df.loc[((row.date == df.index.date) 
            & (df.index.hour == comp_hr))]['Value'].values[0]        
        df.loc[index,'12h-Val>11h-Val?'] = base_value > comp_value

df = df.drop(columns='date')
```

then print to get the result you're looking for:

```
print(df)
```

Comment: The first part worked, but when trying to compare the two values, it throws an error saying: *Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects*

Comment: would you mind clarifying how this comparison will be used? my snippet is based on the column heading suggesting we're comparing hour 12 to hour 11 and there are several hour 12s and hours 11 and the result are returning a series and that would produce a boolean.

Comment: Ok, at the beginning we have a dataframe with two columns, "Time" and "Value" what we need it's to compare the values between the different Time rows, for example: *Is Value at 12:00 > Value at 10:00* and then store the bolean answer in a new column in the same dataframe

Comment: Your error: 'Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects' is the result of comparing multiple rows with hour = 12 to multiple columns with hour = 11 and won't return anything. the function 'Is Value at 12:00 > Value at 10:00?' will need to compare a single row and would have to specify either a full date for both and read 'Is Value at 2018-11-09 12:00:00 > Value at 2018-11-09 10:00:00' and that will only ever return a single result. If that is what you're looking to accomplish, that would be better suited in a function - what is the entire program output? df may not be right for this.

Comment: yeah, what I'm doing is data analysis, I need to compare the values according to the hours. I'll research to see if I find a solution, If you got something, please share it here, Thanks man

Comment: how do you know which date to compare? will it always be the hour previous?

Comment: No, it can be any comparison, but all between different hours of the same day